# CircleCI runs zero tests on my maven Java project

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, pipeline, circleci, cicd

I have a test project that is built with Maven (Java). I can either execute the test from IntelliJ manually or from the command line by writing `mvn test`.

I put the project on CircleCI and it generated a yml file. And it was able to execute the tests on pipelines as well without any issue at first

Then I made something stupid. Initially tests were in this root: `src/main/java/api/test`. But I decided to move the test class to this root: `src/test/java/api`.

I did this change because `src/test/java` was the actual test folder created automatically when you create a Maven project. (The other test folder was created by me manually so I thought this was not the best practice and therefore decided to move the test class to `src/test/java`. Basically what I did is, I created a package named `api` under `src/test/java` and moved the test class to this package. After that I deleted src/main/java/api/test as it is empty now.

After this change, I didn't observe any issue. I could still run the tests from IntelliJ or from the command line by `mvn test` command. But after I commit my changes, I just checked the pipelines and saw this:

```
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.793
```

My project is still built and tested on CircleCI but it obviously does not execute the test class. I dont know why it is happening. I checked the yml file and there is nothing related with paths and it was working before. Here is my yml file:

```
# Use the latest 2.1 version of CircleCI pipeline process engine. 
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference
version: 2.1

jobs:
  # Below is the definition of your job to build and test your app, you can rename and customize it as you want.
  build-and-test:  
    # These next lines define a Docker executor: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/executor-types/
    # You can specify an image from Dockerhub or use one of our Convenience Images from CircleCI's Developer Hub.
    # Be sure to update the Docker image tag below to openjdk version of your application.
    # A list of available CircleCI Docker Convenience Images are available here: https://circleci.com/developer/images/image/cimg/openjdk
    docker:
      - image: cimg/openjdk:11.0
    steps:
      # Checkout the code as the first step.
      - checkout
      # Use mvn clean and package as the standard maven build phase
      - run:
          name: Build
          command: mvn -B -DskipTests clean package
      # Then run your tests!
      - run:
          name: Test
          command: mvn test

workflows:
  # Below is the definition of your workflow.
  # Inside the workflow, you provide the jobs you want to run, e.g this workflow runs the build-and-test job above.
  # CircleCI will run this workflow on every commit.
  # For more details on extending your workflow, see the configuration docs: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#workflows
  sample: 
    jobs:
      - build-and-test
```

As I said the same yml file was working fine before I moved the test class. Now it probably can not locate my test file. What could be the problem here and how can I solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the first step you run with: `-DskipTests` which runs the whole life cycle without any test. Then `mvn test` which repeats a lot of steps which does not makes sense... just use a single step: `mvn -B clean package`...

Comment: I didn't create the yml file. It was auto generated by CircleCI. And as I said in the post, it was working fine before I moved the test files to somewhere.

And regarding to your suggestion, in which line exactly should I write `mvn -B clean package`?

Comment: Nevertheless the generated yml file is sorry to say that rubbish. Remove the lines starting `# Then run your tests!` up to the line including `command:`... and remove the previous `command:` with `command: mvn -B clean package` and try that.